# JApplet window is blank in netbeans

Tags: java, swing, japplet

I created `Test.class` that extends `JApplet`. When I run the code, the open window appears blank and doesn't show any string.
How can I solve this issue?

```
package test;

import java.awt.Graphics;
import javax.swing.JApplet;

public class Test extends JApplet {       

    @Override
    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        g.drawString("Hello World!", 0, 0);
    }

    @Override
    public void init() {
        repaint();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In [`drawString()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics.html#drawString-java.lang.String-int-int-), `x` and `y` are the leftmost character's [baseline](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/FontMetrics.html). With no descenders, your text is entirely outside the rendering area. Try

```
g.drawString("Hello World!", 5, g.getFontMetrics().getAscent());
```

See also [*Initial Threads*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html).